# How to move lines to table cells

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, table-of-contents

I have some data separated into lines and want to move it to some table cells, each line in a cell, so if I have 1000 lines it will be in 1000 cell, like:

```
line1
line2
line3
```

will be a table with 3 cells each one represent a cell(line1, line2, line3).

Comment: Your last sentence is not clear. Do you want a table with 3 columns ?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer No, I corrected it, I want to fill the table with my lines by putting each line in a table

Comment: That means, your 1000 lines should be 333 tables with 3 cells each and an orphan line ? Is this what you mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the text, then use Insert | Table. (On the menu that appears, rather than using the grid, just click Insert Table.